# Recover unallocated partition (Windows Storage Space/Pool)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, data-recovery

I have 4 3TB drives in raid-5 via Storage Spaces in Windows 10.  In mid-copy of file the system froze/rebooted and the drive is now listed as "Unallocated".  I had concerns using the Storage Spaces solution in windows (just seemed that it could be unstable).  The drives are connected via eStata bus multiplier to an external bay.  All 4 drives show a green light.  Storage spaces sees the drive with all 4 drives combined as being "ok" but again, Disk Manager shows it as unallocated.  I've used a couple partition recovery tools (ie. Easeus and Minitool) to scan for the partition to no avail.  I've used the Easeus data recovery tool and it found 4 of the 140,000+ files on that drive. Before I throw in the towel I thought I'd ask here for any advice.

Sorta sad that a fault tolerant solutions like this completely failed me.

Comment: You had a single point of failure since you had an external bay.  This means any fault tolerance you did have by using RAID 5, was lost when the entire RAID was likely disconnected.  To tell you exactly what happened that would involve looking at the event logs.  Of course, the reason the fault happened, really isn't important just that you find a way to restore the file system.  The problem is that tools like TestDisk might not work in a case like this.

Comment: Yea I was concerned of that "single point of failure" although I don't know how else I could have configured raid 5 and windows short of a gigantic case and all internal drives.  I wonder if doing a raid-0 combining 2 sets of drives then mirroring the raid-0 would be better.

Comment: I wouldn’t use Storage Spaces with external drives, only internal, this allowing you to have multiple points of failure (each sata connection).